# Executable jar file blocked by Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, java, ftp, firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically allow an executable JAR file through Windows Firewall?](https://superuser.com/questions/489467/how-to-programmatically-allow-an-executable-jar-file-through-windows-firewall)

I have created a program in Java that uses an FTP connection to download files. It works just fine when I run it in Eclipse. I exported the project to an executable jar file and now the program does not connect to the FTP server, it connects only if I disable my Windows Firewall. How can I programmatically add an exception to this jar file in the firewall so that the user would not have to turn off the firewall to use my program?