# How to programmatically allow an executable JAR file through Windows Firewall?

Tags: java, windows, ftp, firewall

I have created a program in Java that uses an FTP connection to download files. It works just fine when I run it in Eclipse. However, when I export the project to an executable JAR file, the program does not connect to the FTP server, it connects only if I disable Windows Firewall.

How can I programmatically add an exception to this JAR file in the firewall so that the user would not have to turn off the firewall to use my program?

Comment: All connections pass through the java.exe interpreter. If its added in the firewall, nothing can block making new connections.

Comment: You cannot programmatically add an exception to the firewall. Otherwise every program could do that - and thereby compromise the firewall.

Comment: Ok, how i can programmatically ask exception in firewall, like some programs do. Popups window that ask for exception.

Comment: If you are unable to make the connection, just display the message, to add the exception to the user's firewall.

Comment: @Prototype Stark Not true, there is an API available for this and it works fine. I've tested [this native code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can wrap this in the native layer and call it through Java, or write a VB script to do it, or any other number of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, added "netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable" via command promp, the code:

```
try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your windows firewall settings, you have an "Exceptions" tab. Add "java" or "javaw" or whatever you use there as an exception. You can also add port 20 and port 21 to the list of exceptions.

Comment: Tried that, did`n worked.

Comment: Sure you added the right java.exe and/or javaw.exe? Exactly the one that is called when you double click on the jar?

Answer (score 3):

**`-> Control Panel -> Systems and Securtiy -> Windows Firewall -> Allowed Programs`**

You have to add java.exe interpreter to the firewall. You cannot add a .jar file to the firewall of windows.

Comment: Tried that, did`n worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add exceptions to the firewall so your program can get though without disabling it totally.

http://support.lexisnexis.com/us_en_us/record.asp?bRFS=1&ArticleID=10093

Exceptions can be added automatically, run the following commands.

Add firewall rule:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start runas /user:domain\administrator /savecred:cmdrun.txt netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”FTP Service” action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in");`

Disable stateful ftp filtering:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start runas /user:domain\administrator /savecred:cmdrun.txt netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable");`

Also, make sure your ftp connection is in passive mode.